# How to ignore taking revision of few files in perforce?

Tags: perforce

We have few files checked-in in perforce like **@sample.json. Such file names are not supported on Windows, so I get below exception in p4v perforce application when I take revision.

```
**sample.json: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I do not want these files on my local box. How can I ignore such files in p4v ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the section on ASCII expansion in the doc on file specs:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/o.fspecs.html

You can use this syntax to exclude files with asterisks in their names from your client view:

```
//depot/... //client/...
-//depot/...%2A... //client/...%2A...
```

If you want to actually sync these files and substitute the invalid characters you can do that too.  For example:

```
//depot/... //client/...
//depot/...%2A%2A... //client/...WTF-WHO-PUTS-A-DOUBLE-ASTERISK-IN-A-SAMPLE-FILENAME...
```

will cause a file called `**sample.json` to be synced to your workspace as `WTF-WHO-PUTS-A-DOUBLE-ASTERISK-IN-A-SAMPLE-FILENAMEsample.json`.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore/disregard certain files and exclude them from your client workspace, put them into your client view with a '-' in front of them.

Something like:

```
View:
    //depot/project/... //my/client/project/...
    -//depot/**/*sample.json //my/client/**/*sample.json
```

Comment: I had to use %2A for * as mentioned by Sam Stafford. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you **literally** meant that the file contained an asterisk in the name. Good catch by Sam for understanding that!